# Ubuntu Mate Black screening problem

Tags: laptop, acer, 15.10, mate

So my Acer Aspire E5-511-P2D6 and I decided to install Ubuntu Mate 15.10 (I've been getting this problem with all distros and distribution versions from 14.04+) So I installed it but now I'm getting these problems:

Laptop sometimes won't boot or freezes on boot.

Laptop will freeze and run cpu fan at max if I try putting it in Suspend or try rebooting.

My laptop after login will put brightness at full bars but for some reason the brightness slider is in reverse. (Fn + Arrow keys)

Please help?

Comment: ease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.